# Fade in/out Image in UIIamgeView happens with no duration

Tags: uiimageview, ios11, uianimation, swift4, xcode9

I have a `UIIamge` I created programmatically in `viewDidLoad` of a `DetailViewController`.  I would like to `.transitionCrossDissolve` between its current image to another image.  My problem is that once the `DetailViewCOntroller` is displayed the switch happens right away no matter the `duration`.  I never even see the first image.  I am using the following code.

```
    let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.height, width: view.frame.size.width, height: view.frame.size.height / 3.0)
    let imageView = UIImageView(frame: rect)
    imageView.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "head1")
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    imageView.clipsToBounds = true
    view.addSubview(imageView)
    UIView.transition(with: imageView,
                      duration: 16.0,
                      options: .transitionCrossDissolve,
                      animations: { imageView.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "head3") },
                      completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to start the animation in the `viewDidAppear` delegate. Think thats the problem.